# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

Please help for the build error.

Kotlin version : 1.5.31
Gradle-zip: 7.2
Gradle version: 7.0.3

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> 2 files found with path 'kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins' from inputs:
> /Users/Umut/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/98f5d2ab243e47179d111ce52d349da0/transformed/jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.5.31.jar
> /Users/Umut/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3af4d33202657704115aebc723152cf8/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.jar
> Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
> https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html for more information

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
apply from: "$rootDir/ktlint.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.umut.example"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        useIR = true
    }

    bundle {
        //Generate APKs for devices with different screen densities//
        density {
            enableSplit true
        }
        //Generate APKs for devices with different CPU architectures//
        abi {
            enableSplit true
        }
        //Create a split APK for each language//
        language {
            enableSplit false
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

    //test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:$truth_version"
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:$mockk_version"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$robolectric_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$archCoreTest_version"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"

    //kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutines_version"

    //hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$dagger_hilt_version"
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_hilt_version")

    //retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:$retrofit_coroutines_adapter_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshi_version"
    kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshi_version")

    // okHttp3
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$okHttp_version"

    //compose
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:$compose_activity_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$compose_view_model_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:$constraintlayout_compose_version"

    //3rd
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:$lottie_version"
    implementation "com.pinterest:ktlint:$ktlint_version"
    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:$security_crypto_version"
    kapt "androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx:$security_crypto_version"

}
```

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
        security_crypto_version = "1.1.0-alpha03"
        google_services_version = "4.3.10"
        lifecycle_version = "2.4.0"
        lifecycle_extensions_version = "2.2.0"
        kotlin_coroutines_version = "1.5.2"
        kotlin_serialization_version = "0.20.0"
        compose_version = '1.0.5'
        constraintlayout_compose_version = '1.0.0-rc02'
        compose_activity_version = '1.4.0'
        compose_view_model_version = '2.4.0'
        okHttp_version = '4.9.2'
        retrofit_version = '2.9.0'
        moshi_version = '1.12.0'
        dagger_hilt_version = '2.38.1'
        retrofit_coroutines_adapter_version = '0.9.2'
        lottie_version = '4.2.0'
        truth_version = '1.1.3'
        mockk_version = '1.12.1'
        robolectric_version = '4.7.2'
        archCoreTest_version = '2.1.0'
        ktlint_version = "0.43.0"
        multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$google_services_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$dagger_hilt_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the following dependency:

```
implementation "com.pinterest:ktlint:$ktlint_version"
```

`ktlint` must not be added as a dependency. See [official documentation](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint#-with-gradle) for installation instructions.

Comment: I am getting same error and I don't have any 3rd party dependencies. Please check: https://notepad.pw/umu1ff23

Comment: @JaineelMamtora you can locate which dependency causing such error with binary search: comment all of them to see if this helps, then comment half to locate it, etc